# C++ list insertion strange behavior

Tags: c++, list, class, oop

I have a class called Particle, and another called ParticleList, which is essentially a List of Particles plus some other functions. I'm noticing some strange behavior when I try to insert a new particle into ParticleList and I'm wondering why that is happening. The classes are defined as:

```
class Particle {
public:
    // Particle data members
    int index;
    vector<double> r_last;
    vector<double> r;
    vector<double> v;

    double m;
    double q;

    Particle(int i, double m, double q, int ndim) :
            index(i), m(m), q(q) {
        r_last.resize(ndim,0);
        r.resize(ndim,0);
        v.resize(ndim,0);};

    Particle() { };
    Particle(const Particle& p);
}
```

and

```
class ParticleList : public list<Particle> {
public:
    int highestIndex;
    size_t numParticles;
    ParticleList() {highestIndex = 0; numParticles=0;}


      /*below are functions that call the List<Particle>::push_back() 
      and List<Particle>::push_front() functions and increment numParticles*/

   void push_back(const Particle& p);
   void push_front(const Particle& p);

   //some more member functions here

};
```

Definition of push_back and push_front:

```
void ParticleList::push_back(const Particle &p) {
    numParticles ++;
    list<Particle>::push_back(p);
}

void ParticleList::push_front(const Particle &p) {
    numParticles ++;
    list<Particle>::push_front(p);
}
```

The trouble comes in when I try to insert a particle as follows:

```
    ParticleList newParticleList;
    Particle newParticle(1, 0.5, 0.5, 2); 
    /*creates a particle with index 1, mass and charge 0.5, and 2 dimensions. 
Variables r, r_last and v are set to vectors {0,0}*/

    for (int i=0;i<nDim;i++)
        newParticle.r[i]=0.5 //just changed newParticle.r, everything else still {0,0}

    newParticleList.push_back(newParticle);
```

For some reason, when I do the last step, the value of the r_last vector for the list member that just got inserted changes to the value of the r vector. So if I print out newParticle.r_last, that'd give me {0,0}, but if print out the member of the list:

```
auto ii=newParticleList.end();
ii--;
Particle p=*ii;
for(int i=0;i<p.size();i++)
    cout<<p.r_last[i];
```

I get {0.5,0.5}, which is the value of p.r. If I change the r vector after this point, it doesn't affect the value of r_last...only when I push_back does it create this effect. I've tried different computers, removed optimization flags, tried push_front and insert, and it's still the same behavior. Does anyone have ideas on what might be causing this?

Thank you!

Siddharth

Comment: General advice: Don't derive from types without virtual destructor, which is the case for most types from `std`.

Comment: You set `Particle.r` but you print `Particle.r_last`, we do not know the link between these two. We also do not know the implementation of `push_back` (which is probably not declared as you did since it takes a parameter... ), and within `push_back` there is probably a copy constructor of `Particle` but you did not show its implementation. By defaulting the copy constructor, making `ParticleList::push_back` only call `list::push_back` with a `const Particle&` and printing `r` instead of `r_back`, the code works, so please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My sincerest apologies, I made a typo in the declaration of push_back and push_front. It takes a reference to the particle as an argument. I've corrected that now and added the definitions of both functions.

Comment: @SiddharthKrishnamoorthy I am pretty sure the problem comes from the copy constructor of `Particle` - What do you get if you use the default one (`Particle(const Particle& p) = default;`)?

Comment: Indeed, just checked the copy constructor, and that had p.r being copied into r_last. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SiddharthKrishnamoorthy If you do not need a custom copy constructor are using c++11 (or later), use the default copy constructor (see my previous post) - This will save you a lots of trouble.

Comment: @Holt: Thanks for the tip! This specific part of the code was written previously by someone else, so I will investigate why it is that we need to use a custom copy constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `Particle p=*ii;` you create a copy of `Particle` object. So check your copy constructor `Particle(const Particle& p);`. May be it incorrectly copies `p.r` into `p.r_last`.

Comment: Oh wow. Spot on! Indeed, I changed that it works now. Thank you!